# Git clone from svn repo with no trunk directory and place files in root of git repo

Tags: git-svn

I'm importing code from a svn repository with a structure as follows:

```
Repo/
  branches/
  tags/
```

The repository doesn't have a trunk.

Code is kept in the subdirectory ProjectName, so when it's checked out I see

```
Repo/
  ProjectName/
    Files
```

When I execute:

```
git svn clone -t tags -b branches https://servername/svn/Repo GitRepo
```

I get a git repository at GitRepo and everything imports correctly, the problem is that whenever I check out files in git it checks them out into the ProjectName subdirectory like:

```
GitRepo/
  ProjectName/
    Files
```

My question is, is there any way way to tell git svn to clone the repo in such a way that I get:

```
GitRepo/
  Files
```

So, what I'm asking is if I can tell git to use a folder that only appears when a branch is checked out as the root for the repository.

Comment: How do you get `GitRepo/ProjectName/Files` structure? For me that `git svn clone` creates a git repository for each project in my repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://servername/svn/Repo
    branches = branches/*/*:refs/remotes/branches/*/*
    tags = tags/*/*:refs/remotes/tags/*/*
```

in .git/config

The second /* in the branches and tags strings being the important part I was missing before.

Thanks to ChrisA for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, one bit of information is missing from the answer I think... I had to remove the --stdlayout from my git svn clone command to keep it from changing the config file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this, but you'll need to specify the trunk, branches and tag locations manually (as they're non standard in your case).

Create you're repo like so: `git svn init https://servername/svn/Repo GitRepo`

Then open up you .git/config file and the url, fetch, branches and tag lines so that it looks like the following:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://servername/svn/Repo
    fetch = ProjectName:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

The important line here is `fetch = ProjectName:refs/remotes/trunk` which has created a link between ProjectName on the remote and trunk locally.

Comment: I want to achieve something similar. I have a repository, which has no trunk, it just has 30 projects in it, each having its own trunk. I want  to migrate to git but when I do, it migrates with the trunk folders in each project. I tried your solution, but then it is per project, is there a way to write one config file, which will do it for 30 projects?